# Curl (35) trying to install Gitlab Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: 18.04, server, curl, openssl, gitlab

Hi i'm trying to install gitlab on an virtual server Ubuntu 18.04, following [these steps](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu) from the official website.

But when in the second step `curl -v https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh | sudo bash` I'm receiving:

```
    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 54.153.54.194...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to packages.gitlab.com (54.153.54.194) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to packages.gitlab.com:443
* stopped the pause stream!
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to packages.gitlab.com:443
```

Curl version: curl 7.58.0;
OpenSSL: 1.1.1

Anyone knows how can i fix this? or at least investigate deeper.

Thanks

Edit: wget does not work either. It returns:

```
--2021-08-05 19:40:01--  https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh
Resolving packages.gitlab.com (packages.gitlab.com)... 54.153.54.194, 2600:1f1c:2d4:8900:17a1:2e94:9f90:f91e
Connecting to packages.gitlab.com (packages.gitlab.com)|54.153.54.194|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
Converted links in 0 files in 0 seconds.
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you changed anything? Does `wget` download the script?

Comment: wget does not work too.
--2021-08-05 19:40:01--  https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh
Resolving packages.gitlab.com (packages.gitlab.com)... 54.153.54.194, 2600:1f1c:2d4:8900:17a1:2e94:9f90:f91e
Connecting to packages.gitlab.com (packages.gitlab.com)|54.153.54.194|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
Converted links in 0 files in 0 seconds.

Comment: How about `curl -vvv https://example.com`?

Comment: https://example.com works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you have certificate errors like this you should always make sure  you are accessing the correct websites and you are not redirected somewhere else.. but in your case I do not think it's the case.

In order to fix this do:

```
apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

This should clean your repos cache and update everything. You have an old version of curl and OpenSSL and this issue I think is OpenSSL related.

Upgrade everything and it should work.

If not, to bypass ssl checks use:

```
curl --insecure https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh
```